# How can I get the index in PageView Flutter

Tags: flutter, indexing, flutter-pageview

I have a problem and don't know how to solve it, so I want to use an index in PageView and can't use PageView.builder because I have two pages one static HomeBody() and the other is not static and I need an Index for it.

```
final controller = PageController(initialPage: 0);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => CityData(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: PageView(
          controller: controller,
          children: [
            HomeBody(),
            FavoriteCityScreen(
              i: the Index,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Should the index come from `CityData`? Also, would you please [edit] your question and add the `FavoriteCityScreen` widget code.

Answer (score 1):

`FavoriteCityScreen` is only visible while index is 1 on PageView. You can use `FavoriteCityScreen(i: 1)`

```dart
children: [
   HomeBody(),
   FavoriteCityScreen(
   i: 1, //the Index
    )
  ],
```

Comment: I want a dynamic Index not a static

Comment: How you are providing `children`?

Answer (score 1):

To get the index whenever the `tab` is changed, add the callback `onPageChanged(int index)`

```
PageView(
  ...,
  onPageChanged: (index){
    this.index = index;
  },
),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use add listener to get the page or index number.
This is what I did.       `_pageController.addListener(() { print(_pageController.page!.round()); });`